# Get var from controller to model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got one variable in controller (`$id`), I want to pass it to the model:

CONTROLLER:

```
public function user_load_more($id, $friendly_url)
{
    $user = User::where('friendly_url', '=', $friendly_url)
        ->with('shares_load_more.links.tag', 'userProfile.get_following')
        ->with(['shares_load_more.links.page' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'friendly_url');
        }])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

    return view("site.list.user.links", compact("user"));
}
```

MODEL (`User.php`): (?)

```
public function shares_load_more($id) //--- put the id here?
{
    return $this->hasMany(Share::class, 'user_id', 'id')
        ->select('id', 'link_id', 'user_id', 'shared_in', 'content', 'created_at')
        ->take(2)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->where('id', '<', $id)
        ->where('type', '=', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to pass variable in a model, there is an alternate method to do it.

```
public function user_load_more($id, $friendly_url)
{
$user = User::where('friendly_url', '=', $friendly_url)
    ->with('shares_load_more.links.tag', 'userProfile.get_following')
    ->with(['shares_load_more' => function($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('id', '<', $id);
}, 'shares_load_more.links.page' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name', 'friendly_url');
    }])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

return view("site.list.user.links", compact("user"));
}
```

Model:

```
public function shares_load_more($id) //--- put the id here?
{
return $this->hasMany(Share::class, 'user_id', 'id')
    ->select('id', 'link_id', 'user_id', 'shared_in', 'content', 'created_at')
    ->take(2)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->where('type', '=', 0);
}
```

It will append to the relation query

Comment: Don't works, return the same last shares... The where('id', '<', $id) don't works...

Comment: you need to dump the toSql and check if the relation query is including the condition.